# AngularJD: Blank Items appearing in ng-repeat on first button click, items appear when clicking button again

Tags: javascript, html, rest, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a pretty web application that connects to a RESTful API. My HTML has a "View Employees" button that when clicked, makes an API call to grab all the employees for that company. I am checking the return for the API, and it's getting the entire list, but the page is only rendering the first employee and then blank spaces for the rest. Things get stranger when I go to a different company and click on their View Employees button, because the employees for that company appear, AND one of the blank spaces in the previous company suddenly renders properly. I'm reading the return from the API, and it has all the information I need in a properly formatted way. I'm really confused.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Here's my HTML. If you need more code please let me know.

```
    <div ng-if="sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].employees.length > 0">
    <div class="employee-box" ng-repeat="employee in sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].employees">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-right" ng-click="sigFigCtrl.toggleEmployeeEdit($index)"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" ng-click="sigFigCtrl.deletePerson(employee._id, $index, sigFigCtrl.companies[$parent.$index].employees)"></span>
        <div ng-if="!sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].editEmployee">
            <div ng-if="sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].employees.length > 0">
                <p><b>Name:</b> {{employee.name}}</p>
                <p><b>Email:</b> {{employee.email}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="sigFigCtrl.companies[$index].editEmployee">
            <form name="editPersonForm" ng-submit="sigFigCtrl.editPerson(employee._id, $index)">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="sigFigCtrl.editPersonName" id="name" placeholder="Name of Employee" class="form-control" required></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="sigFigCtrl.editPersonEmail" id="name" placeholder="Email of Employee" class="form-control" required></input>
                    </div>
                    <button>SUBMIT</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post your api returned data please

Comment: and post your controller code please